# SQL error log can't create/write to file

Tags: permissions, sql

I'm quite new to server administration but a keen learner, so if I miss anything or you need any extra info let me know and I'll do my best to provide it ASAP :)

I'm running WordPress on a developer plan VPS over at media temple (meaning I have root access, everything is managed by me etc). My OS is Fedora, Apache is latest version and am using MariaDB for MySQL.

When trying to read/write menus from the WP admin panel Apache writes this to its error log:

```
[Fri Dec 13 04:28:59.296672 2013] [:error] [pid 11195] [client (my IP, omitted)] WordPress database error Can't create/write to file '/var/tmp/#sql_1ff_0.MAI' (Errcode: 2) for query (**lots of different queries**)
```

This error repeats for about 20 different queries, and I've checked with perror that error code 2 for SQL means "No such file or directory".

I would contact my host about this problem, but as I said I'm on a developer plan meaning they won't help me with anything. Generally from Googling around I can find an answer or solution but in this case I've come up with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `perror` command to get an explanation on system errors:

```
~]$ perror 2
OS error code   2:  No such file or directory
```

It may be that the directory `/var/tmp/` does not exist.

Alternatively the WordPress MySQL user may not have been granted sufficient permissions to create files. You may need to GRANT `FILE` and/or `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES` priviliges to the WordPress user.  Refer to the the [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) manual page.

Comment: Or the permissions on `/var/tmp` may be wrong (should be 1777).

Comment: @HBruijn /var/tmp does exist (from root, that's where I presume you're referring to). Additionally, my WordPress MySQL user has access to `FILE` and `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES` privs.

@MadHatter The permissions on /var/tmp are 1777 and I've even changed the ownership to mysql[27].

Comment: I would love to hear any other suggestions though, because I'm exhausted. I've spent over 18 hours researching and trying to fix this 1 stupid problem

Comment: More reasons not being able to write could be a full partition (`df`), read-only volume (`mount`) or possibly SELinux related (`getenforce`).

Comment: All mounts have loads of space, the file system is not read-only because I am able to create folders/files manually, and getenforce=disabled.

This whole problem is getting to be a bit of a joke.. Would it be worth trying setting a tmpdir in my.cnf for SQL (I've tried once, yes I made sure mysql had permissions for the new directory but it still didnt work)? Is there any more detailed method of debugging this error to find out more info?

Comment: The .MAI file exention is apparently used by the MariaDB aria engine for indexes. So it may be an `INDEX` privilege?